# Is it possible to ignore GitHub files for sync only?

Tags: git, github

I’m pretty new to GitHub, but I’m using it for some time now for local version tracking of small web development projects. Suppose I have a project that contains a bunch of HTML, CSS and JS files but also a PHP file to access a MySQL database. The PHP file contains my MySQL credentials including password, so obviously I don’t want to make this file public. I want to keep track of all changes to my project locally, including the PHP file, but in case I wanted to put the project online, I needed some way to exclude this file from syncing.

So my question is: Can I ignore a file from syncing with my GitHub account while still being tracked in my local repo? And in case I’m totally on the wrong track, I’ll be happy to hear more solid solutions to this problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can use .gitignore, but this will not commit the changes in your local repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions to omit parts of files, but those are too complex for when you are just beginning using *git*. Most tricks evolve around so called *filters*, commands that parse and create files on checkout on your production site. But you don't need these.

The easiest trick gives you the additional benefits of making the application a bit more secure and more portable.

It is safer because all the secret data is kept in one file that can get really strict permissions (so that people who have access to e.g. FTP onto the codebase, cannot see the creds). 
It is better portable, because it allows your team to run their own credentials on their own development machines the way they want them. e.g. someone using XAMP may have different database-names then someone using virtual machines or homebrewn scripts to manage their project.

On the server, create a file `/path/only/www-data/has/read-access/secret.inc`

```
<?php
/** Hashing **/
define("SECRET_HASH", "hogwards");

/** Database **/
define("DB_USER", "harry");
define("DB_PASS", "alora");
?>
```

Then, in your `settings.php`, or where you store these creds now,:

```
<?php
require("/path/only/www-data/has/read-access/secret.inc");
// Or slightly more portable
// require("../etc/secret.inc");
?>
```

You can also check in an example `secret.inc` for new collaborators, `secret.inc.example`, having the defines, but with empty strings as values.

Now you can simply push `settings.php` along with all other commits. And it will pick up the "secrets.inc" as found on production; using the proudction-server login details for e.g. your database.

Comment: Yeah, I reckoned the example with the DB credentials in a PHP file would be a bad practice example.. thanks for the detailed alternative option, and also for the hint towards git filters. I’ll definitely have a look into that.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to push commits while omitting some of the content.  Doing so would cause the SHA1 identifier to change, resulting in a different commit.

You could do the public development on one branch, and then merge those changes into another branch where you track the configuration information which needs to be kept private. Since you can switch branches while carrying uncommitted changes, you could even do most of the development and testing with the private branch checked out only switching to the public branch to do the commit then switching back and merging those changes in.

But, you would need to be careful when pushing to only push your public branch and not the private branch.  In general it is a much better idea to keep the information that you don't want to push in a small separate file which can safely be ignored from tracking altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore files being tracked on your git repository. That very common for similar cases.

There is a file called .gitignore on the root of you project. In this file you put the path of the files you don't want to track in the git repository.

Please, find a complete explanation on how to use at: https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files

In your case, you will have to manually send this "database configuration" files to your server.

Comment: I do want to track all files in my local repo, I just don't want to sync them all. So .gitignore doesn't help here.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, but I do think you're not doing it correctly. It is a bad practice to store credentials in a PHP file. You should have a different file with settings, but then again, depending on where you put that settings file and how important it is to have a stub settings file in your repository, you might be back to the same problem, but in a different file.